# BigQuery CSV Export to GCS: set Content-Type header to "text/csv"

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm exporting a bigquery table as a CSV to a public Google Cloud bucket.  From there I can host it publicly over HTTP.  The BigQuery export (aka extract) feature doesn't seem to set the file's Google Cloud Storage metadata correctly.

The exporter sets the Content-Type field to be `application/octet-stream`.  Because it's a CSV file, I want it to be set to `text/csv` (or maybe `text/plain`).  Why?  As google outlines [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding), that's a best practice for a variety of reasons.

I don't see any option in the [api documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.extract) to control this.

Another issue: when I set `configuration.extract.compression` to be `GZIP`, the resulting file in GCS doesn't have the `Content-Encoding` property set to 'gzip'.  It would be nice if the exporter did that too!

Comment: Is this a question or a feature request? As a feature request, you can file and track them in the following url: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

Comment: Hey @Felipe Hoffa -- it's a question to ask whether this is possible in the current system.  If the answer is 'no' then I'll file a feature request (or possible it's a bugfix, because the default behavior seems a bit wrong IMHO).

Comment: I now take it that there is no way to set these fields (but please confirm this with an answer if you know for sure), so I've created a ticket in the issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111662658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata) says, `application/octet-stream` is set when the uploader doesn't specify the content type. As in this case, BQ export is the uploader and you cannot specify it, it's going to be set as that. I saw that you created a feature request asking for that.

A workaround would be editing the metadata of each file in GCS bucket. You can achieve this by using the UI, console or coding [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata).