# pandas dataframe to_csv method content type text/csv

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform

I have below code to upload csv to gcp

```
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data)
        df.to_csv("gs://bucket/file_name, index=False )
        s_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = s_client.bucket("bucket")
        blob = bucket.get_blob("file_name")
        metageneration_match_precondition = None
        metageneration_match_precondition = blob.metageneration
        blob.metadata = {"Content-Type": "text/csv"}
        blob.patch(if_metageneration_match=metageneration_match_precondition)
```

It is uploading correctly, but the content type is **application/octet-stream** , how can we change it to **text/csv**

I have updated code as per suggestion, still its not working,

Any help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [`upload_from_string`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_upload_from_string) accepts a `content_type` *parameter* :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data)

s_client = storage.Client()
bucket = s_client.bucket("bucket")
blob = bucket.blob("file_name")

blob.upload_from_string(df.to_csv(index=False), content_type="text/csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure, but changing the metadata may work.

```
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(file_name)

# Set the content type to text/csv
blob.metadata = {"Content-Type": "text/csv"}
blob.patch()
```

Also, mentioned here:

- [BigQuery CSV Export to GCS: set Content-Type header to "text/csv"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424615/bigquery-csv-export-to-gcs-set-content-type-header-to-text-csv)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33320634/6146801

**Google ref:** https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-set-object-metadata-python

**Edit object metadata:**

```
from google.cloud import storage


def set_blob_metadata(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Set a blob's metadata."""
    # bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
    # blob_name = 'your-object-name'

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)
    metageneration_match_precondition = None

    # Optional: set a metageneration-match precondition to avoid potential race
    # conditions and data corruptions. The request to patch is aborted if the
    # object's metageneration does not match your precondition.
    metageneration_match_precondition = blob.metageneration

    metadata = {'color': 'Red', 'name': 'Test'}
    blob.metadata = metadata
    blob.patch(if_metageneration_match=metageneration_match_precondition)

    print(f"The metadata for the blob {blob.name} is {blob.metadata}")
```

**Another Way:**

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563216/6146801

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("<mybucketname>")

blob=bucket.blob("<CSV Name>.csv")

# build up the complete csv string
csv_string_to_upload = ''

# upload the complete csv string
blob.upload_from_string(
            data=csv_string_to_upload,
            content_type='text/csv'
        )
```

Comment: I am uploading csv to gcp storage, not downloading

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563216/6146801

Comment: does it (previous comment link) work, or not? if yes, I'll update the post; if not, I'll search for another way, or delete this post so as not to redirect people in the wrong way.

Comment: No, I have updated the post as well, as per your suggestion I tried, but meta data is not changing, its still application/octet-stream

Comment: did u try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563216/6146801  (previous comment). using "blob.upload_from_string(data=csv_string_to_upload,content_type='text/csv')"

Comment: no, i tried changing the content type

Comment: @ÖmerSezer, that's funny how you edited your answer to include a copy of mine :p.

Comment: @Timeless no it is not yours, I wrote the link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563216/6146801 ) from 1 hour ago in the comments (before u wrote). the way of doing is mentioned there.. You can see it on the link and history of the comment.. I asked to him to try before u wrote. I try to help him. You can get reputation.. It is noneless..